# Decimal not getting while dividing

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am new to python.
I divided two numbers but, I no get decimal part.

```
amount = 1000
people = 3
average = total_amount/total_people
print average
```

I am getting o nly 333 not 333.33
How to solve this? I am ubuntu user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
amount = 1000
people = 3
average = float(amount)/float(people)
print average
```

OR

```
from __future__ import division
amount = 1000
people = 3
average = amount/people
print average
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python2 you should convert one of the numbers to float:

```
average = float(total_amount) / total_people
```

Another option is to use the backported division operator from Python3:

```
from __future__ import division

amount = 1000
people = 3
average = total_amount / total_people
print average
>> 333.333333
```

(This will work if you of course use the correct variable names).